# How to extract a substring separate by square braquet and generate substrings

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract and construct some strings after identifying a substring that matches a pattern contain within square braquets:

> e.g: if my text is '2 cups [9 oz] [10 g] flour '
>
> i want to generate 4 strings out of this input:
>
> 1. "2 cups" -> us
> 2. **"9 oz"  -> uk imperial**
> 3. **"10 g" -> metric**
> 4. **"flour" -> ingredient name**

As a beginning I have started to identify any square braquet that contains the oz keyword and wrote the following code but the match is not occurring. Any ideas and best practices to accomplish this?

```
    p_oz = re.compile(r'\[(.+) oz\]', re.IGNORECASE) # to match uk metric
    text = '2 cups [9 oz] flour'

    m = p_oz.match(text)

    if m:
        found = m.group(1)
        print found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `search` instead of `match`.

```
m = p_oz.search(text)
```

`re.match` tries to match the entire input string against the regex.  That's not what you want.  You want to find a substring that matches your regex, and that's what `re.search` is for.

Comment: I used a match instead but forgot to put it - sorry

Comment: Always copy and paste your code to be sure you post the code you are actually using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just expanding upon BrenBarn's accepted answer. I like a good problem to solve during lunch. Below is my full implementation of your question:

Given the string `2 cups [9 oz] [10 g] flour`

```
import re

text = '2 cups [9 oz] [10 g] flour' 

units = {'oz': 'uk imperical', 
         'cups': 'us', 
         'g': 'metric'}

# strip out brackets & trim white space
text = text.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').strip()

# replace numbers like 9 to "9
text = re.sub(r'(\d+)', r'"\1', text)

# expand units like `cups` to `cups" -> us`
for unit in units:
    text = text.replace(unit, unit + '" -> ' + units[unit] + "~")

# matches the last word in the string
text = re.sub(r'(\w+$)', r'"\1" -> ingredient name', text)

print "raw text: \n" + text + "\n"
print "Array:"
print text.split('~ ')
```

Will return an array of strings:

```
raw text:
"2 cups" -> us~ "9 oz" -> uk imperical~ "10 g" -> metric~ "flour" -> ingredient name

Array: [
 '"2 cups" -> us', 
 '"9 oz" -> uk imperical', 
 '"10 g" -> metric', 
 '"flour" -> ingredientname'
]
```

Comment: Thanks - I am trying to get an answer right now following my first approach

Comment: Yes and I'd recommend whatever you've been working on vs. this little snippet I threw together over lunch. Good luck!